# Circular reference between modules?

Tags: python

If have this module

```
# mymodule.py
import __main__
```

And I import it in the python interpreter:

```
>>> import mymodule
>>> dir(mymodule)
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__file__', '__main__', '__name__', '__package__']
>>> dir()
['__builtins__', '__doc__', '__name__', '__package__', 'mymodule']
>>> import sys
>>> sys.modules['__main__'] == mymodule.__main__
True
>>> mymodule == mymodule.__main__.mymodule
True
```

I've just created a circular reference by importing a module that imports `__main__`. Is this bad?

Comment: `Is this bad?` [Yes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-pattern).

Comment: why on earth would you want to import `__main__`?

Comment: @tokenmacguy: You're not accustomed to people asking hypothetical question for the sake of learning the deeper principles?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No. Python has no problem with circular references like this. The only thing you must be sure of is that you don't use a name from the other module until it has been defined.